# Check if specific character is inside a word or in front/behind it

Tags: java, regex, character

i have a String (not empty) and i want to remove any special characters except the ' for words like "won't" for example and put it in an ArrayList.

So i did this:

```
    s = s.toLowerCase();

    //Replace any special characters except " " and "'". Also remove Multiple spaces
    s = s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9' ]", "").trim().replaceAll(" +", " ");   
    
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(s.split(" ")));
```

But now i want to delete every ' that is not inside a word. F.e. when i have something like " 'hello World".

I tried this:

```
        for(String word : words){
            //if the ' is at the start of the word or after a space or before a space
            if(word.matches("(?<=^| )'|(?! )'")){
                word = word.replaceAll("'", "");
            }
            if(word.length() != 0)
                //if the word was not only containing ' add it to a new ArrayList
                newwords.add(word);

        }
```

But that does not work. I just learned about regex and i am having a difficult time.

It should also recognize words like ''' for example.

Edit:
Some examples:

s = " ''' "

return: empty List

---

s = "a #bbb' %$ c' won't"

return: [a, bbb, c, won't]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: How about `'Tis the season to be jolly`? `Sellers' market`? `Gone surfin'`?

Comment: Can you please add 1-3 examples

Comment: This is just a programming excercise so i can ignore things like "surfin'"  "Sellers' market" and all this. But it would be interesting how to handle these as well. Probably manual definition of every word that could have this? But thats unrealistic i guess. I dont know

Comment: Okay so this method should for example return an empty list if i give it s = "     '''     ". It should return ["a", "bbb", "c", "won't"] if i give it s = "a    #bbb' %$ c'     won't"

Comment: Add the examples to the question itself, by clicking [edit]. It's hard to understand in a comment, and some characters disappear in comments.

Comment: Does the exercise require the use of regex for this?  It would be fairly easy to loop through a String looking for `'` characters and checking the adjacent characters.

Comment: Thank you for the reply VGR. It does not require regex necessarly. Its just that i learned regex in university and i wanted to learn it by using it. It would be great to find a solution with regex. 

But i didnt think about just looping through the string and checking adjacent characters. That is a good solution!

Comment: @atiixx, I'm added variant with `StringBuilder`, this variant faster `~x127` (with `50 000` characters)

Answer (score 0):

#### Code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(get("\"\"")));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(get("a #bbb' %$ c' won't")));
    }

    
    private static String[] get(String s) {
        char cs[] = s.toCharArray();
        String newString = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < cs.length; i++) {
            char c = cs[i];
            if(Character.isWhitespace(c)) { // if character is space-symbol (tab, space, newLine and et al) when we release this on " "
                newString += ' ';
                continue;
            }
            if(Character.isAlphabetic(c)) { // if character is Alphabetic when we not release this on something
                newString += c;
                continue;
            }
            if(i+1 < cs.length && i > 0) {
                if(c == '\'' && Character.isAlphabetic(cs[i+1])
                        && Character.isAlphabetic(cs[i-1])) { // if character is apostrophe and it's between the letters when we not delete this character 
                    newString += c;
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        
        String superNewString = "";
        cs = newString.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < cs.length; i++) { // replace double spaces
            if(cs[i] == ' ' && i > 0) {
                if(cs[i+1] != ' ') {
                    superNewString += cs[i];
                }
            }else {
                superNewString += cs[i];
            }
        }
        return superNewString.split(" ");
    }
}
```

#### Console:

```
[]
[a, bbb, c, won't]
```

#### Code with `StringBuilder`:

```
private static String[] fastGet(String s) {
        char cs[] = s.toCharArray();
        StringBuilder newString = new StringBuilder();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < cs.length; i++) { 
            char c = cs[i];
            /*
             * if character is space-symbol (tab, space, newLine and et al)
             * when we release this on " "
             */
            if(Character.isWhitespace(c)) {
                newString.append(' ');
                continue;
            }
            /*
             * if character is Alphabetic
             * when we not release this on something
             */
            if(Character.isAlphabetic(c)) {
                newString.append(c);
                continue;
            }
            if(i+1 < cs.length && i > 0) {
                /*
                 * if character is apostrophe and it's between the letters
                 * when we not delete this character 
                 */
                if(c == '\'' && Character.isAlphabetic(cs[i+1])
                        && Character.isAlphabetic(cs[i-1])) {
                    newString.append(c);
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        
        StringBuilder superNewString = new StringBuilder();
        /*
         * replace double spaces
         */
        for (int i = 0; i < newString.length(); i++) {
            if(newString.charAt(i) == ' ' && i > 0) {
                if(newString.charAt(i+1) != ' ') {
                    superNewString.append(newString.charAt(i));
                }
            }else {
                superNewString.append(newString.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        return superNewString.toString().split(" ");
    }
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you were to explain what you did to solve the problem, and why.  A code dump by itself is rarely a good answer, since it doesn’t help others improve their programming ability.  Also, using `+=` on a String in a loop is a bad practice, as it creates a considerable amount of extra String objects;  always use StringBuilder for that.

Comment: @VGR, Yes, I just wanted to add a variant with `StringBuilder`, thanks for reminding me

Comment: Hey thank you for the answer. This is a really good approach i didnt think about yet. 
Some Problems though. If you have leading whitespaces, they don't get fully removed and if you have multiple white spaces at the end  i get a OutOfBounce exception because of the "if(newString.charAt(i+1)" at the replace double space loop. 

But these are things i can fix on my own, so thank you for the idea :) i still would love a solution with regex

Comment: @atiixx [this can help](https://ihateregex.io/)